# Random Pairing in Socket.io chat room

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm making a chat application using socket.io which is simple enough, but the catch is that the users need to be paired randomly. The logic I am using is in the server I generate 100 uuids and then send them to a connecting client. The client then connects to a room with 1 user, if there is no such room, they connect to a room with 0 users. I get no errors, so I can only assume that something went wrong with room joining, but I'm not sure what exactly.

My code is here:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>anon</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
      <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <div class="title">
    <p1>anon</p1>
  </div>
    </body>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    const room;
    const ones = [];
    const zeroes = [];
    function randNum(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }
    function checkName(){
        var name = prompt("enter name:");
        if (name === null) {
      name = "Anonymous User"+parseInt(randNum(0,1000));
            return name;
    }else{
            return name;
        }
        
    }
  var socket = io();
  var username = checkName();
    
    socket.on('all_rooms', rooms1 {
    for(roomx in rooms1){
            if(io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomx).size == 1){
                ones.push(roomx);
            }else if(io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomx).size == 0){
                zeroes.push(roomx);
            }
        }
  });
    if(ones.length>0){
        room = ones[0];
    }else{
        room = zeroes[0];
    }
    console.log(room);
    
  socket.emit("joined", username, room);
  var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input.value) {
      input.value = username+': '+input.value;
      socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
      input.value = '';
    }
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = msg;
    messages.appendChild(item);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  });

  window.setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('messages');
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
    console.log('yes')
  }, 10);

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
const users = {};
const { v4: uuid } = require('uuid');

const rooms1 = [uuid(),uuid()];

for (let i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
  rooms1.push(uuid());
}

io.on("joined", () => {
  socket.emit('all_rooms', rooms1);
});



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
server.listen(443, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:443');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    let username = users[socket.id]["username"];
    let room = users[socket.id]["room"];
    io.to(room).emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on("joined", (username, room) => {
    socket.join(room);
    io.to(room).emit("joined", username);
    users[socket.id] = { username: username, room: room };
    
    console.log('people online:', users);

  });
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    let username = users[socket.id]["username"];
    let room = users[socket.id]["room"]
    io.to(room).emit("leave", username);
    delete users[socket.id];
    console.log(users);
  });
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  let username = users[socket.id]
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(username, 'disconnected');
  });
})
```

Comment: you shouldn't have three `connection` event listeners on the socket.

Comment: @about14sheep My chat was working fine with the three connection event listeners before I implemented the random connection feature so that can't be it.

Comment: might have, but having three will lead to unexpected errors, as it is incorrect to implement them this way. You can add all that logic into one connection listener